# Mokito cannot be imported into java

Tags: java, import, mockito

I am trying to use mokito in java.  typing

```
import org.mokitio.Mockito;
```

in eclipse creates the response

the import org.mokito cannot be resolved.

Google says:

http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

> Download mockito-all-x.x.x.jar and put it on the classpath. If you use
>   a fancy build system with declarative dependencies like Gradle or
>   Maven please -> Click HERE <-

how do I put something in my classpath?

Comment: You need to add the jar as wekll

Comment: The import has to be `org.mockito.Mockito`, not `org.mokitio.Mockito` as is currently in your question

Answer (score 0):

[image: Libraries showing Mockito jar added]... Once you have added the jar here, your eclipse compiler errors will go away.